# ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, python-3.8

I installed pip3 using `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` after that when I run the following command to install django `sudo pip3 install django` I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in 
> from pip import main
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 14, in 
> from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 23, in 
> from pip.locations import (
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in 
> from distutils import sysconfig
> ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/**init**.py)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I have tried recently manually installing python3.9 version in my Ubuntu from 3.6 version using `apt install python3.9`. Then pip3 was broken. The issue is because distutils were not build for the 3.9 version.

So in my case I ran `apt install python3.9-distutils` to resolve my issue.

In your case make sure to modify 3.x version in distutils command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it help me to resolve my issue

Comment: i.e. run `sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils`

Comment: for me : `sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils` worked also.

Answer (score 17):

This helped but then I got another error: ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'

The following fixed it:

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall

Comment: I encountered a similar error on python 3.10 and could fix it with `python3.10 -m ensurepip --upgrade`